# Math mode brackets `\[...\]` without centering

Tags: math-mode, brackets

I'd like to be able to put math mode in distinguishable opening and closing brackets, like `\[...\]`, instead of `$...$`, but the problem is, `\[...\]` seems to be auto-centering the equation.

Is there a way around that?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting stuff inside `\(...\)`? The `\[...\]` is for "displayed math" (i.e. on a line of its own), while `\(...\)` and (equivalently) `$...$` are for inline maths mode.

Comment: @rbrignall how foolish of me, indeed, it worked. Thank You!

Comment: Consider using the AMS packages if you are into (heavier) math.

Comment: @vonbrand oh, I sure am, doing just that. That is why having `\(...\)` is convenient, because having `$` everywhere makes it very difficult to keep track of pairs.